# TFS with SSMS 2014

Tags: windows-8.1, ssms-2014

I've system with SSMS 2014. Windows 8.1 OS connected with remote server 2008R2Standard having SQL Server 2008R2 and TFS 2010.

My system doesn't required visual studio stuff, so I don't have anything else. I just installed with SSMS 2014 for my DB work, DB on my server.

Now I need source control in my system. Tried all required installation things, but Can't get the **Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider** under SSMS IDE->Tools->Options->Source Control->Current Source Control Plug-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider 32 bit & it's working.